# How to use snyk commands in the build-in Webstorm terminal

Tags: npm, terminal, command-line-interface, snyk

I installed Snyk with "npm i -g snyk". It was installed successfully.

However I can not authenticate with "snyk auth" in the terminal. It shows a error message that the command "snyk" couldn't be found.

How can I use the snyk commands in the terminal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I had to add the path of snyk into the collection of the global path variables.